# Canonical(normal) from of the system of differential equations.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I've got this system of differential equations
$$\begin{cases} 
x''=f(t,x,x',y,y')\\
y''=g(t,x,x',y,y')
\end{cases}$$

Where $f$ and $g$ are given and known functions and $x=x(t), y=y(t)$

Is there any algorithm or method to bring this system to canonical(normal) form?

Comment: What canonical normal form are you refering here? Of course, you can transform this system of *two* equations of the *second order* to the system of *four* equations of the *first order*. It's very easy to do, but I'm not sure that this is what you mean here.

Comment: Evgeny that's exactly what I wanna do, how can I do that?

Comment: The equivalent system is $$ \left \lbrace \begin{array}{ccc} \dot{x} &=& u \\ \dot{u} &=& f(t, x, u, y, w) \\ \dot{y} &=& w \\ \dot{w} &=& g(t, x, u, y, w)  \end{array} \right . $$